# Configurable Map Viewer (CMV) - add tabs to widget

Tags: dojo, configurable-map-viewer

I m trying to add a tab panel with three tabs in a widget, but I get the following message in the debugger:

> nested divs because wipeIn()/wipeOut() doesn't work right on node
>   w/padding etc. Put padding on inner div.

How can this be solved?

Comment: This is really a question about dojo, not CMV. Can you provide some example code from your widget?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for tabs like this, I have these in one of my Widgets.

[image]